# How do I write a Hibernate query in which the returned list is different sub-classes of an abstract class?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 4.1.0.Final.  I have a MySql 5.1 table mapped to an abstract class.  How do I build a Hibernate query in which I iterate over the table, building my return list in which I instantiate a different sub-class based on the row's ID?

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have mapped the class hierarchy correctly

```
session.CreateQuery("from AbstractEntity").list();
```